# Are there tools that emulate (mobile) 'screen glare'?

Tags: mobile, accessibility, applications

Simple question, is anyone aware of a tool that can emulate screen glare for websites / apps? Specifically for mobile screen glare.

Comment: Do you mean a visual effect that can be applied to an image (or an app) to make it look like someone's using a phone in sunlight? If so, _perhaps_ (but check their help pages) https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ may be a better place to ask?

Comment: Could you explain why you would need this? Simulating realistic glare is going to be very difficult. Might be obvious but get a device and a lamp..

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a screen glare texture on top of your UI in any graphics editor (Photoshop, for example in screen blending mode with levels adjustment of the image) or to make it an overlay image in your website. Example of such texture: [image] 
Alternatively, you can use screen mirroring software (for example [psmirror](http://www.psmirror.net/en)) to test the UI on the real device during UI development.

I don't think there is any software that emulates screen glare, especially for mobile devices.